# Any methods to deploy Python packages with 'pip | easyinstall' + '*.pyc only' + 'flat namespace packges' + virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, packaging, setuptools

Goals:

- Make use of modern Python packaging toolsets to deploy/install proprietary packages into some virtualenv.
- The installed packages should include compiled *.pyc(or *.pyo) only without source files.
- There are a couple of packages, and a vendor name (here we choose *dgmx* for our studio) is used as the package names. Therefore, the installed packages would be something like *dgmx/alucard*, *dgmx/banshee*, *dgmx/carmilla*, ...
- The file hierarchy of installed packages should be like ones by `python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed` or `pip install`. Refer to [How come I can't get the exactly result to *pip install* by manually *python setup.py install*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172286/how-come-i-cant-get-the-exactly-result-to-pip-install-by-manually-python-set/10173805#10173805)

Question in short:

I like to deploy proprietary namespaced packages into a virtualenv by only compiled *.pyc(or *.pyo) files, in which the file/directory hierarchy just reflects the namespace with polluting *sys.path* by lots of *ooxx.egg* paths.

Something I have tried:

1. `python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files` then `easy_install ooxx.egg`.

   - pollute "sys.path" for each namespace package.
2. `python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed`.

   - not *.pyc only.
   - the "install_requires" got ignored!
   - need to manually put a *ooxx.egg-info/installed-files.txt* to make *uninstall* work correctly.
3. `pip install .` in the location of "setup.py".

   - not *.pyc only.
4. `pysetup install .` in the location of "setup.py".

   - not *.pyc only.

**Update**:

My current idea is to follow method 2.

- `python setup.py egg_info --egg-base .` # get requires.txt
- `python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record installed-files.txt` # get installed-files.txt
- manually install other dependencies through "requires.txt"
- manually delete installed source files (*.py) through "installed-files.txt"
- remove source files (*.py) from "installed-files.txt" and put it into deployed "ooxx.egg-info/installed-files.txt"

References:

1. [Migrating to pip+virtualenv from setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981174/migrating-to-pipvirtualenv-from-setuptools)
2. [installing only .pyc (python compiled) with setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730686/installing-only-pyc-python-compiled-with-setuptools)
3. [Can I deploy Python .pyc files only to Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002150/can-i-deploy-python-pyc-files-only-to-google-app-engine)
4. [How come I can't get the exactly result to *pip install* by manually *python setup.py install*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172286/how-come-i-cant-get-the-exactly-result-to-pip-install-by-manually-python-set/10173805)

Comment: FYI, pyc are not really compiled binaries, and can easily be reverse engineered, e.g. using the `dis` module.  I would suggest looking at pyd files (which are basically dlls), but I'm not sure how you can create them from python code.

Comment: I know, but it's a policy issue instead of robust technical issue.

Comment: @Drake: you probably want `.pyo` files instead of `.pyc`.

Comment: @vartec you're right. `.pyo` is much better then~

Answer (score -1):

Some trick may help:

Compile your source into `.pyc`, zip them up in a single `.zip` file.

Write a new module with a simple module all it does is to add the `.zip` to the `sys.path`.

So when you import this module, the `.zip` is in the path. All you have to do is in a custom step in `setup.py`, copy the zip file to the proper place.

Comment: In case of Python called an `egg`, and he already mentioned that in the question (first option he has tried).